# Where can I find a list of the iOS platform capabilities?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, platform, capability

I'm making an application that tells the user what kind of iOS device they are using and then tells them the device's capabilities.  Below is some example code:

```
case UIDevice1GiPhone: return UIDeviceBuiltInSpeaker | UIDeviceBuiltInCamera | UIDeviceBuiltInMicrophone | UIDeviceSupportsExternalMicrophone | UIDeviceSupportsTelephony | UIDeviceSupportsVibration;
case UIDevice3GiPhone: return UIDeviceSupportsGPS | UIDeviceBuiltInSpeaker | UIDeviceBuiltInCamera | UIDeviceBuiltInMicrophone | UIDeviceSupportsExternalMicrophone | UIDeviceSupportsTelephony | UIDeviceSupportsVibration;
case UIDeviceUnknowniPhone: return UIDeviceBuiltInSpeaker | UIDeviceBuiltInCamera | UIDeviceBuiltInMicrophone | UIDeviceSupportsExternalMicrophone | UIDeviceSupportsTelephony | UIDeviceSupportsVibration;           
case UIDevice1GiPod: return 0;
case UIDevice2GiPod: return UIDeviceBuiltInSpeaker | UIDeviceBuiltInMicrophone | UIDeviceSupportsExternalMicrophone;
case UIDeviceUnknowniPod: return 0;
case UIDevice3GSiPhone: return UIDeviceSupportsGPS | UIDeviceBuiltInSpeaker | UIDeviceBuiltInCamera | UIDeviceBuiltInMicrophone | UIDeviceSupportsExternalMicrophone | UIDeviceSupportsTelephony | UIDeviceSupportsVibration;
```

This is exactly the kind of stuff I'm looking for.  The first line means that the 1st Generation iPhone has a built in speaker, a built in camera, it supports an external microphone, etc.  Does anybody know where I can get a complete list like this for all of the devices?  The list I have is missing: iPhone 4, iPhone 4s, 3rd gen iPod, 4th gen iPod, and all generations of the iPad.  Thank you.

Comment: Refrain from introducing custom constants/defines/functions/classes that start with UI...

Comment: @matt - I think you misunderstood the OP; he's asking how to get the properties of the iDevice that the app is running on. For example, if I download this application, the application will tell me whether I have a built-in speaker, camera, etc.

Comment: @qegal I think *you* misunderstand the OP. Look at his code. He is not introspecting the device; he's writing an encyclopedia of model capabilities, similar to [MacTracker](http://www.mactracker.ca). The problem is that he doesn't _know_ the model capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for lists of capabilities, you might want to check out Wikipedia for [iPhone model comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iphone#Model_comparison), for [iPod touch models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipod_touch#Models), and and [iPad technical specifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipad#Technical_specifications).

You can also google the specific device you're looking for plus the word "specifications" (e.g. "iPod touch 3rd generation specifications") and you'll generally get a ton of hits, often including a page on Apple's own site (e.g. see [3g touch specs here](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP570)).